# How to plot a graph with a side bar as a legend using Floris lib from NREL?

Tags: python-3.x, floris

I am using the Floris library from NREL for Python in order to simulate wind wakes after a wind turbine (see https://github.com/NREL/floris). In the example 1 of section "Getting Started" (see https://github.com/NREL/floris/blob/main/examples/_getting_started/example_00_open_and_vis_floris.py) I am plotting the result for a single turbine. This is the output:

[Wake for 1 turbine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT8S2.png)

However, I would like to add the side legend bar on the right (see black circle), like in the next figure:

[Wake turbine with side bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVUiU.png)

I cannot show the full code because the floris library from NREL has a lot of user-defined functions (this is why I provide the links). The code for the example I mentioned is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import floris.tools as wfct
# Initialize the FLORIS interface fi
# For basic usage, the florice interface provides a simplified interface to
# the underlying classes
file_dir = '...\example_input.json'
fi = wfct.floris_interface.FlorisInterface(file_dir)

# Calculate wake
fi.calculate_wake()

# Get horizontal plane at default height (hub-height)
hor_plane = fi.get_hor_plane()

# Plot and show
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
wfct.visualization.visualize_cut_plane(hor_plane, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been solved by NREL's team:

```
# Plot and show
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = wfct.visualization.visualize_cut_plane(hor_plane, ax=ax)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I have added the next part to improve the visualization:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = wfct.visualization.visualize_cut_plane(hor_plane,ax=ax)
cax = fig.add_axes([ax.get_position().x1+0.01,ax.get_position().y0,0.02,ax.get_position().height])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, label='m/s') # alternativa: fig.colorbar(...)
```